# receiver 1 can approve to send money to receiver 2 in chained paypal payments?

Tags: paypal, chained-payments

receiver 1 can approve to send money to receiver 2 in chained paypal payments ?

Please see picture in link

http://image.ohozaa.com/i/240/O3um1P.jpg

Ok, i'm market place and i'm receiver 1

When sender send money , normally receiver 1 and receiver 2 will get money immediate

But i want to set new function , my function is receiver 2 will get money when receiver approve

can i do that on chained paypal ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are wanting to do delayed chain payments. [See the user guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/). You can set up step 4 in any way you see fit. On your system you can make any or all of the parties agree to pay the secondary receiver, then call the `ExecutePayment`.